# How to convert octal escape sequences with Python

Tags: python

I extract javascript code from PDF, but it is converted octal escape sequences.

I want to convert it to normal JavaScript code.

```
\040\040\040\040\146\165\156\143\164\151\157\156\040\163\167\050\051\17....
```

Please advise me.

Comment: See the linked duplicate if you actually have a string with backslashes in it (for example, by reading data from the PDF). If you just have something like that in your source code, then nothing needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for both Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
>>> b'\040\040\040\040\146\165\156\143\164\151\157\156\040\163\167'.decode('utf-8')
'    function sw'
```

Comment: If you use escaped sequence (non-raw-string), you don't need to use `decode`.

Comment: Yeah but you end up with a byte array instead of a string.

Comment: You're right. Without the `decode` call, you will get a `bytes` objects. (but only in Python 3.x)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`unicode_escape` encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

In Python 2.x:

```
>>> r'\040\040\040\040\146\165\156\143\164\151\157\156'.decode('unicode-escape')
u'    function'
```

In Python 3.x:

```
>>> br'\040\040\040\040\146\165\156\143\164\151\157\156'.decode('unicode-escape')
'    function'
```