# Python Conver Octal Escaped String to Data

Tags: python

**My code :**

```
'''
Content of Hello.txt is  only ->    \251

Actually \251 represents ©

'''

prefix = "PREFIX"
suffix = "SUFFIX"

f = open('Hello.txt')
d = f.read()
f.close()
print prefix+d+suffix
```

My Problem is,this prints **PREFIX\251SUFFIX** but I actually want it to print **PREFIX©SUFFIX**

As per [How to convert octal escape sequences with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173340/how-to-convert-octal-escape-sequences-with-python) I tried to d.decode('utf-8'), But still the same problem.

Comment: You have the *literal text* ``\``, `2`, `5`, `1`, so four characters. What kind of file format do you have? Is it RTF text or something similar perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clarify your string as unicode for python , you can use `unicode` function as following :

```
>>> print unicode('PREFIX\251SUFFIX','unicode-escape')
PREFIX©SUFFIX
```

Comment: Nope, you are correct, the text contains the literal text.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , he write the text above of the code ! ;)

Comment: Got this error :ActivePython 2.7.5.6 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 16 2013, 23:16:52) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print unicode('PREFIX\251SUFFIX','unicode-escape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>