# Convert octal representation of UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I have a variable like this:

```
>>> s = '\\320\\227\\320\\264\\320\\260\\320\\275\\320\\270\\320\\265 \\320\\261\\321\\213\\320\\262\\321\\210\\320\\265\\320\\271'
>>> print(s)
\320\227\320\264\320\260\320\275\320\270\320\265 \320\261\321\213\320\262\321\210\320\265\320\271
```

This contains the octal escape representations of the UTF-8 encoding of the string "Зданиебывшей" (octal `320 227` = hex `D0 97` = UTF-8 for "З"). How can I decode this string to "Зданиебывшей"?

Comment: my question is different.. @deceze.. i cant write b'\320\227\320\264\320\260\320\275\320\270\320\265 \320\261\321\213\320\262\321\210\320\265\320\271' cuz i get the octal values as a string object dynamically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23173435/476…? No? What is the expected result?

Comment: the octal values are in a STRING object. i cant decode a string object without converting it into a byte object right? so if I convert a string object to bytes, the octal content changes. I have to convert the values in a string variable(which are already octal) to byte object without changing the octal values so that i can decode it

Comment: True. Then you're probably looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/24519338/476.

Comment: ;-; this one is entirely different. I think you dont get my question. I just want to convert a string object (contains octal values) into a byte object. example: 

str = "\320\320\320" 

i have to make this into a byte object like this

byte_str = b'\320\320\320'

Comment: @DhamoR how did you get the string?

Comment: How's it different exactly? From one of the answers there: `bytes('\\320\\227\\320', 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')` → 'Ð\x97Ð' – What result do you expect, why doesn't this technique work for you?

Comment: If you say `print` gives *\320\227\320*, then the correct literal for your string would be `"\\320\\227\\320"`, correct?

Comment: it actually represents Зданиебывшей in octal. you can check it here http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/octal/

Comment: So that is a string containing the octal representation of the UTF-8 encoding of the string Зданиебывшей…? You will have to clearly state that in your question.

Comment: b = bytes([int(i, 8) for i in str.split("\\")[1:]])

Comment: i guess i gave that in the explanation stating that the 'hello' value is a string object

Comment: @matt nope.. it gives empty byte array

Comment: You should include the assignment of the string, to show what the actual string is. And the value you expect.

Comment: sorry that I didnt explain the question properly. So i think now it is clear. @deceze can you pls remove the duplicate markers as this question is not duplicate?

Comment: @DhamoR it works for me. `s = "\\320\\227"` `bytes([int(i, 8) for i in s.split("\\")[1:]])` gives me `b'\xd0\x97'`

Comment: matt, you have encoded the string to form a set of new octal values.. where as my string object already has the octal value. And @deceze thanks for the edit

Comment: `b'\xd0\x97'.decode('utf-8')` → З…

Comment: cool.. got it. thanks matt and deceze

Comment: @DhamoR isn't that exactly what you want? Unless somebody points you to a decode from octal escaped values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert "\x" escaped string into readable string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218987/convert-x-escaped-string-into-readable-string-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack.

```
s = '\\320\\227\\320\\264\\320\\260\\320\\275\\320\\270\\320\\265 \\320\\261\\321\\213\\320\\262\\321\\210\\320\\265\\320\\271'

b = bytes([int(i, 8) for i in s.split("\\")[1:]])

print(b.decode("utf8"))
```

yields: `Зданиебывшей`

Or use the `codecs` module.

```
b2 = codecs.escape_decode(s)[0]
print(b2.decode("utf8"))
```

Which would yield the same result.