# Decode individual octal characters in string variable

Tags: python, string, variables, octal

A string variable sometimes includes octal characters that need to be un-octaled. Example: `oct_var = "String\302\240with\302\240octals"`, the value of `oct_var` should be `"String with octals"` with non-breaking spaces.

[Codecs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/codecs.html) doesn't support octal, and I failed to find a working solution with `encode()`. The strings originate upstream outside my control.

Python 3.9.8

Edited to add:
It doesn't have to scale or be ultra fast, so maybe the idea from [here](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/743965-converting-octal-escaped-utf-8-a) (#6) can work (not tested yet):

```
def decode(encoded):
    for octc in (c for c in re.findall(r'\\(\d{3})', encoded)):
        encoded = encoded.replace(r'\%s' % octc, chr(int(octc, 8)))
    return encoded.decode('utf8')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert octal representation of UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621340/convert-octal-representation-of-utf-8)

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP there -- "i cant write b'\320...\271' cuz i get the octal values as a string object dynamically".

Comment: One link from there (thx) this looks like a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python/24519338#24519338, scroll to "Adding a regular expression to solve the problem" and below.

Comment: see updated answer, given the info that "the strings originate upstream outside my control".

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to indicate that `oct_var` should be given as bytes:

```py
>>> oct_var = b"String\302\240with\302\240octals"
>>> oct_var.decode()
'String\xa0with\xa0octals'
>>> print(oct_var.decode())
String with octals
```

Note: if your value is already as a string (beyond your control), you can *try* to convert it to bytes:

```py
>>> oct_str = "String\302\240with\302\240octals"  # as a string
>>> oct_var = bytes([ord(c) for c in oct_str])
# often equivalent to:
>>> oct_var = oct_str.encode('Latin1')
```

and then proceed as above.

Note, if the string also contains chars beyond ASCII, (e.g., with Latin1, accented chars like 'é'), the subsequent `.decode()` will fail, as in UTF-8 those are represented as multibyte chars (e.g. `'é'.encode() == b'\xc3\xa9'`, but `'é'.encode('Latin1') == b'\xe9'`). If the string contains Unicode chars beyond Latin1 (e.g. '你好'), you will get a `ValueError` or a `UnicodeEncodeError`, depending on which of the two conversion methods you choose).

In short: don't fly anything expensive, heavy, or with people inside with that -- this is hacky. At the very least, surround your code with `try ... except (ValueError, UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError)` and handle these exceptions accordingly.

Comment: This touches an important point.  Those codes (`\302\240`) are the UTF-8 representation of the non-breaking space, U+0040.  If those octal codes are present in a Unicode string, you have a problem.  You really need to have that as a bytes string, in which case the conversion is easy, as Pierre has correctly shown.

Comment: We are stuck with • solutions that will not vanish suddenly but are not reliable, and • something that is stable enough for the Python devs[1]  but can be gone any time without notice.  `codecs.escape_decode` could go inside a `try ... except` that fires some sort of notification when it is called but no longer provided in Python. Maybe by then we have a replacement.  [1] "…we can not just remove it while it is used in the pickle module, and there is no reason to change it as it works pretty good for its purpose…"

Answer (score 0):

Putting your ideas and pointers together, and with the risks that come with the use of an **[undocumented function](https://bugs.python.org/issue30588)[*]**, i.e, **`codecs.escape_decode`**, this line works:

`value = (codecs.escape_decode(bytes(oct_var, "latin-1"))[0].decode("utf-8"))`

[*] "Internal function means: you can use it on your risk but **the function can be changed or even removed** in any Python release."

Explanations for for `codecs.escape_decode`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059682/5309571

Examples for its use:

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/8498/codecs.escape_decode

Other approaches that may turn out to be more future-proof than `codecs.escape_decode` (no warranty, I have not tried them):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58829514/5309571

https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/743965-converting-octal-escaped-utf-8-a